# Maven mvn spring-boot:run - cannot find local library, fails on command line but runs in STS4

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

my Spring Boot  (v2.2.0.RELEASE) app is called project-service. I want to containerize it and in the process notice that it doesn't run outside Eclipse (STS4). So I wonder what I should change.

The app relies on a small library I wrote to reuse some classes (fscl-core-lib), which is built through Maven as a jar and for now rests on my local machine.

```
 path-to-project/fscl-core-lib/target/fscl-core-lib-0.2.0.jar
```

When I run the application from Eclipse (STS4, in fact), it works. When I try to run from command line, it fails in different ways, no matter what I try, all having to do with not finding the lib.

I have tried so far :

**1) Maven dependency to lib**

in project-service/pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.fscl</groupId>
        <artifactId>fscl-core-lib</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>            
    </dependency>
```

this runs in STS4, but fails on CLI with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project project-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project io.fscl:project-service:jar:0.2.0: Failure to find io.fscl:fscl-core-lib:jar:0.2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

**2) Tell Maven where to find the lib jar**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>fscl-core-lib</id>
    <url>file://path-to-project/fscl-core-lib/target</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.fscl</groupId>
    <artifactId>fscl-core-lib</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>            
</dependency>
```

This runs in STS4 but fails on CLI with :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project project-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project io.fscl:project-service:jar:0.2.0: Failure to find io.fscl:fscl-core-lib:jar:0.2.0 in file:///path-to-project/fscl-core-lib/target was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of fscl-core-lib has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

so it does go to the local repository but seems to expect a different filename. How can I determine the filename produced by the lib build process, and what should it be ?

**3) As a last resort, include the jar in the class path**

In STS4, for project-service, Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Add external JARs..., then select `path-to-project/fscl-core-lib/target/fscl-core-lib-0.2.0.jar`

This runs in STS4 but fails with compiler errors on the CLI, as it doesn't find anything from the libs packages.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fscl/core/FSCLEntity
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

I have searched the web up and down to come up with these three approaches and are currently out of wits. It must be something totally obvious, or I am following some totally wrong aproach in general ?

Any advice most welcome.

For Reference, here is the pom.xml of the library:

fscl-core-lib/pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>io.fscl</groupId>
<artifactId>fscl-core-lib</artifactId>
<version>0.2.0</version>
<name>fscl-core-lib</name>
<description>Library with cross-service reusable classes for FSCL system.</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And the applications project-service/pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>io.fscl</groupId>
<artifactId>project-service</artifactId>
<version>0.2.0</version>
<name>project-service</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>fscl-core-lib</id>
    <url>file://path-to-project/fscl-core-lib/target</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.fscl</groupId>
        <artifactId>fscl-core-lib</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>            
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.bechte.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-hierarchicalcontextrunner</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: In the fscl-core-lib project, run `mvn install` to install it to your local maven repository. This should allow you to build the other project from the command line.

Comment: LucasP, you nailed it. Thanks.

Comment: To wrap it up: I of course can get rid of the <repository> item in my project-service/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

So,

as LucasP advised, running mvn install in the lib project does the trick, as it installs the jar into the local repository (~/.m2 ... ).

Meantime, I instead chose to create a separate repository in the **depending** projects and to deploy the lib jar into that ([see this article](https://sookocheff.com/post/java/local-maven-repository/)).

This way, once I need to build a new version of the lib, (1) I update it's version info in it's pom.xml, (2) build it with `mvn package`, (3) run a `mvn deploy:deploy-file` command for each depending project (I maintain these in a `deploy` bash script in the lib folder).